# Can someone explain why hjk isn't printing everytime I click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, dom-events

Can someone explain why **hgk** isn't printing every time I click? When I click on button every time it should run debounce function and it should print 'hgk', but why this isn't printing it.
Can any of you can explain it to me with clear explanation?

```js
const debounce=(fn,delay)=>{
     
    let timer;
     console.log('hgk');
      return function(){
        console.log('nbm');
     clearTimeout(timer);
        timer= setTimeout(fn,delay);            
       }
 }

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',debounce(()=>{
  
  console.log('clicked')
},2000));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/bovesapoyu/edit?html,js,console,output)-hjk isn't printing hjk.

Comment: Please create a code snippet here

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>


const debounce=(fn,delay)=>{
 

let timer;
 console.log('hgk');
  return function(){
    console.log('nbm');
 clearTimeout(timer);
    timer= setTimeout(fn,delay);
  
  
}
}



document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',debounce(()=>{
  
  console.log('clicked')
},2000));

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read above link shared by @AnuragSrivastava. And update your question  to add the code snippet you have.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple reason why the code is not working. In JavaScript line 33, you referenced a DOM element with the id "button". However, when you look at the HTML panel, it is nowhere to be found.